# Math Round Function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a form that use the following script to calculate the item price including VAT:

```
function calculateTotaleIVA() {
          var tot = document.getElementById('totale').value;
          document.getElementById('totale_prodotto').value = Math.round(tot*121)/100;
          totale_prodotto.value = document.getElementById('totale_prodotto').value.replace(".", ",");
          totale.value = document.getElementById('totale').value.replace(".", ",");
          }
```

This function works fine but I have a questions. Some times the result is like this:

46,4

I want to see at screen two digits after point decimal like this:

46,40

How can I fix the above function to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
(Math.round(tot*121)/100).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `toFixed(2)` for that

toFixed(No of digits)

```
(Math.round(tot*121)/100).toFixed(2);
```

[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)